# Js String of a minus sign into a minus sign

Tags: javascript

I want to have a program that turns "-" into an actual minus sign the computer will recognize.
Here is my code:

```
document.getElementById("answer").innerHTML = (Number(input.substr(Number(input.indexOf("+"))).slice(1)) + Number(input.substr(0, Number(input.indexOf("+")))));
```

Comment: Very nice. Was there a question you had?

Comment: My question is there a method for this. Sorry I wasn't more clear about this above.

Comment: I'm going to be shot for suggesting this, but maybe https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval is what you're after

Answer (score 1):

I take it you're trying to build a calculator. I'd personally create different functions for adding, subtracting, etc. You could use `eval()`, but that's **[prone to XSS](https://stackoverflow.com/q/86513/2341603)**.

Here's a simple calculator showcasing the minus pre-built into the JavaScript calculation, so that you don't have to worry about extracting it from the input:

```js
function add() {
  document.getElementById('answer').innerHTML = Number(document.getElementById('input1').value) + Number(document.getElementById('input2').value);
}

function subtract() {
  document.getElementById('answer').innerHTML = document.getElementById('input1').value - document.getElementById('input2').value;
}
```

```html
<input id="input1">
<input id="input2">
<button onclick="add()">Add</button>
<button onclick="subtract()">Subtract</button>
<div id="answer"></div>
```

Hope this helps! :)